# Terraform: couldn't connect to server

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I cannot connect to the instance that was provisioned with Terraform.

Here is the code:

```
provider "aws" {
    region = "us-east-2"
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
    ami = "ami-0578f2b35d0328762"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.instance.id]

    user_data = <<EOF
                #!/bin/bash
                echo "Hello World!" > index.html
                nohup busybox httpd -f -p 8080 &
                EOF

    tags = {
        Name = "terraform-example"
    }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "instance" {
    name = "terraform-example-instance"

    ingress {
        from_port = 8080
        to_port = 8080
        protocol = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
}
```

And when I try to connect to port 8080 with "curl" I get this:

[image]

It seems strange because I also cannot connect to the instance via EC2 console.

Comment: You are only allowing port `8080` ingress, which means you can't SSH into it (which requires port `22`)  to perform any sort of debugging. And you haven't added an SSH key to the instance, so it won't be available over SSH anyway. I don't see anything in your code adding SSM permissions to the Instance's IAM role, so you won't be able to use AWS SSM Session Manager to connect and debug the issue either.

Comment: You aren't following the correct HEREDOC syntax for your user-data so there are a bunch of added spaces on each line. That would definitely cause a problem. https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/strings You could try changing the code to use `user_data = <<-EOF` for a quick fix (notice the additional `-` character to instruct Terraform to trim the leading white space.

Comment: @MarkB the problem was in a bunch of added spaces. Your last comment really helped. Thank you so much for answering!

Answer (score 1):

OK, the issue was due to incorrect HEREDOC syntax usage. I have deleted all the whitespaces & used Enter-button every time:

[image]

Thanks @MarkB for his help!